# Find curved points from straight line points in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, android-canvas

I have a section which contains circles like this (http://prntscr.com/k2e09u).
But I have to make this curved like (http://prntscr.com/k2e0ee).
I have starting point and end points of each rows and points of circles also.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you ? Do you have some code ? Did you try to solve the problem yourself ? 
If you have the rows coordinates, you just have to assign Y position of every circle to the row coordinate.

Comment: I have tried this way, but I didn't get actual way I want.

Comment: If you want some help, one good way to start with is to post a minimal, testable version of your code that we can reproduce.

Comment: Here is the code sample : https://plnkr.co/edit/S2AJgnAqWJC0V3838q19?p=preview